# Static FileName with date throughout whole process in ssis

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssis-2012

In my SSIS project, I am using a filename with a date (**eg.Daily_20200706.CSV**) and I need to schedule it at 11 PM (ist) and to complete the execution it's taking 3 to 4 hour and in between the filename is getting changed, when the system date is getting changed after 12 PM. So is there any solution for this to make it static the value of filename at the starting.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

1. Create a [variable](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/ssis/ssis-basics-introducing-variables/#:%7E:text=A%20variable%20is%20a%20named,variable%20when%20you%20create%20it.) to hold your file name.
2. Populate the variable as the first task in your pipeline.
3. Use that variable everywhere you need the file name, instead of recalculating it from the current date every time you need the file name.

Comment: I would suggest changing the link to the the Microsoft [SSIS variables documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/integration-services-ssis-variables?view=sql-server-ver15), is very complete, yet the redgate one is more visual

Comment: Yeah, it's hard to judge which one someone new to the tech would prefer. I'll leave my link since you have now provided the alternative as well!